# Cannot get rid of default controller in URL with multilingual codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization, routes, multilingual

When I land on my home page www.domain.com (with default controller 'home') the browser redirects to www.domain.com/en/home.  What I would like to see is www.domain.com/en (google will see these pages as duplicate content I think?)

Is it possible to leave the default controller out of the URL so that only the language follows the domain i.e. www.domain.com/en?

Here is my code below:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

// '/en', '/es' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|es)$'] = 'home'; //$route['default_controller']; //'home'



// route es translation of girls to girls
$route['es/chicas'] = "girls";
$route['es/chicas/chica/(:num)/(:any)'] = "girls/girl/$1/$2";
$route['es/chicas/etiquetas/(:num)/(:any)'] = "girls/tags/$1/$2";

// movies es routes
$route['es/peliculas'] = "movies";
$route['es/peliculas/pelicula/(:num)/(:any)'] = "movies/movie/$1/$2";
$route['es/fotos/galeria/pelicula/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'photos/gallery/movie/$1/$2';
$route['es/peliculas/etiquetas/(:num)/(:any)'] = "movies/tags/$1/$2";

$route['es/unirse'] = "join";

// general catch all for anything that doesn't fit rules above, but doesn't have a 
// language prefix e.g. en/girls -> girls controller
$route['^(en|es)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
```

Comment: Can u tell, how are you achieving this url www.domain.com/en/home.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have posted the code originally. I have no amended my original post to include the code.

Comment: try to put $route['^(en|es)$'] = 'home'; before $route['default_controller'] = "Home"; I think $route['default_controller'] = "Home"; is not required as you are already doing in the $route['^(en|es)$'] = 'home';  Also make changes on config file for base_url. Try to put es or en which is default there with url.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's about your config/route.php file. Update your routes as you want exactly.

Comment: I have now included my routes file in my original post.